# glut library for Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, glut

hello everyone I'm working with Eclipse under Windows XP, but I can't find there glut library, all I have inside GL are only gl.h, glu.h and glext.h, can somebody please help me import glut library and explain what is this glext.h, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glut can be downloaded from here:

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php

`glext.h` is a header file containing the interfaces for all officially registered opengl extensions.

Comment: how can I import it into eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

1.copy all glut files into their corresponding locations include,lib,GL in x64mingw compiler folder ,and copy the glut.dll into c://windows/system32

2.in eclipse , project->properties_>c/c++ build->settings->mingw -> libraries

3.add these libraries glu32,opengl32,freeglut
this should add the libraries.  :)